# Проход по всем фактам Swi-Prolog

Tags: swi-prolog

Задача: рассмотреть все факты и найти среди них тот, у которого наименьшее значение у одного из аргументов 

Пример:

```
city(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
city(4, 5, 6, 7, 8).
```

Поиск идёт по 4-му пункту, например. Проблема в том, что происходит зацикливание на самом первом факте, дальше поиск новых не происходит.

Как ищу и что делаю:

```
searchByArea(MinArea):-
    city(_,_,_,CurArea,_),
    tempAreaSearch(CurArea,MinArea).

tempAreaSearch(CurArea, MinArea):-
    CurArea < MinArea ->
    (
                  MinArea1 is CurArea,
                  searchByArea(MinArea1),
                  print(MinArea1)
    );
    searchByArea(MinArea).
```

Вопрос: как мне пройтись по всем фактам? 

Так же непонятно, почему при отправке запроса через терминал выводятся абсолютно все факты (при использовании ;), а здесь же всё время мы находимся на одном и том же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, мне помогла процедура **forall**.

В моём случае использование выглядит так:

```
searchByArea(MinArea):-
    forall(city(_,_,_,CurArea,_), tempAreaSearch(CurArea,MinArea) ).

tempAreaSearch(CurArea, MinArea):-
    CurArea < MinArea ->
    MinArea1 is CurArea,
    print(MinArea1).
```

P.S. нахождение минимума не правильное, но вопрос и не в этом заключался.